# Django- limit_choices_to using 2 different tables

Tags: python, django, django-models

I fear that what I am trying to do might be impossible but here we go:

Among my models, I have the following

```
Class ParentCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name 
Class Category(models.Model):
    parentCategory = models.ForeignKey(ParentCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

Class Achievement(models.Model):
    milestone = models.ForeignKey(Milestone, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField( )
    level_number = models.IntegerField()
    completeion_method = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'parentCategory.name':'comp method'})

    def __unicode__(self): # TODO: 
        return description[0,75] + '...'
```

I know the completion method field throws an error because it is not correct syntax. But is there a way to achieve the wanted result using a similar method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
limit_choices_to={'parentCategory__name': 'comp method'}
```